# I need to integrate esign and online pdf edit to my angularJS and Asp.net MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, electronic-signature

I am developing a Real Estate Agents Portal to a USA client. We need to let the users upload pdf files, add textboxes and assign others to fill them and add verified signatures. I am kind of loss from where to start on this. Any guidance will be appreciated..

Thanks!

Regards,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

[Scrive](http://scrive.com/) is a SAAS that lets you do what you ask for in their interface. You basically upload a PDF, place fields on the PDF and send it off to other people to enter data in the fields and draw signatures.

This can also be integrated in to your workflow via [API](http://scrive.com/en/api).